# Register an iOS device

Tags: c#, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, maui, azure-notificationhub

From my `.NET8 MAUI` application, I managed to register successfully the device in the `Azure Notification Hub`. The payload I use for sending the request to the installation API of Azure Notification Hub is like this one

```
{ 
    InstallationId = CD604726-8428-4693-B854-FBF8A13F79BA, 
    Platform = apns, 
    PushChannel = E6A6111438ACAF2221553D861CE8F132EBC32B0E23C8AC15AF77B178F67A9D58 
}
```

When I send a test message, I get an error related to the

> The Push Notification System handle for the registration is invalid

[image]

What is the correct format of the  `Push Notification System handle`? Is this the `PushChannel`? How can I fix it?

Comment: You can find Apple's documentation for how to receive and use a device token on the following two documentation pages:

- [Registering your app with APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering-your-app-with-apns)
- [Sending notification requests to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending-notification-requests-to-apns)

Any time the documentation is referring to a "provider server", it is speaking about Azure Notification Hubs.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track by hex-encoding the device token value. Double check for errors or extra characters. You can reference the way the official ANH iOS SDK does this [on GitHub.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-ios/blob/19c7535590eaa147ddc4f1c9b43e3686e71e8f2a/WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging/SBNotificationHub.m#L80-L89)